# GhostDoc for NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Anyone know of a product similar to GhostDoc for the NetBeans IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Triemax Jalopy](http://www.triemax.com/products/jalopy/) can do some of that, along with wicked cool code formatting.

Comment: Tried Jalopy per your suggestion. Fantastic product with excellent support from Trimex.

Answer (score 1):

The Netbeans built in Javadoc functions do some of this.  Right click on a java file and select tools then analyze javadoc. This will check, fix, and add Javadoc comments with tags.

Did the [Netbeans plugin portal](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/MainPage.jsp) turn up anything ?